# Which tools are available to see embedded image and sound data

Tags: binary-analysis, ghidra, graphics

I'm reverse engineering a program from a memory dump using Ghidra. I know there are sections which contain images and sampled sound data in a raw format.

I'm looking for a tool which will let me view the raw binary as an image so I can find those parts and extract them. Can I do this in Ghidra? Or is there another tool I can use?

Answer (score 1):

You can try X-ways Forensics, it has nice option of analyzing any disk image or memory dump.

Or perhaps another tool such as [Restorator](https://www.bome.com/products/restorator) can also be used for the above mentioned scenario.